# Google Drive API Java: Getting error when trying to move file to trash

Tags: java, kotlin, google-drive-api

I am trying to move a file to trash using the Java Google Drive API. Here's what I've tried doing:

The code:

```
        val file = service.files().get(fileId).execute()
        file.setTrashed(true)
        service.files().update(fileId, file).execute()
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B0XJAu1tqe0ZT01ZSzRLb3Zfa3c
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.",
      "reason": "fieldNotWritable"
    }
  ],
  "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:439)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1111)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:525)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:466)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:576)
    at DriveQuickstart.main(DriveQuickstart.kt:97)
```

Answer (score 0):

The file returned from `service.files().get(fileId).execute()` includes a lot of fields, and some of them must be un-writable.

[image: Debug picture]

I managed to fix this error by just creating an empty File and setting trashed

```
        val file = com.google.api.services.drive.model.File()
        file.setTrashed(true)
        service.files().update(fileId, file).execute()
```